# VHDL is it valid syntax to use string in Generic?

Tags: vhdl

I have been using Xilinx tools for a while, and they are perfectly fine with code such as the following:

```
ENTITY Example IS
  GENERIC(
    g_Mode : STRING  := "Normal"); -- "Normal", "Test"
  PORT(
    Clk : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    -- ETC 
    );

END Example;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF Example IS

Normal_g : IF g_Mode = "Normal" GENERATE
  -- Normal Operation Code Here
END GENERATE Normal_g;

Test_g : IF g_Mode = "Test" GENERATE
  -- Test Operation Code Here
END GENERATE Test_g;
```

However I have recently switched to using Lattice Tools and I get an error the second time I check the g_Mode.  The error is, "Comparison between unequal length arrays always returns FALSE".  So it seems like one of the two generate statements will never execute.  My question is, is this legal VHDL syntax and therefore a problem with the Lattice Tools?  Or should my code style change to not use strings as Generics?

Comment: An error or a warning about unequal lengths?  It's  tool added reflecting the definition of equality for a composite type. (IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators, para 4) . Xilinx's HDL Compiler will return a similar message as a warning, which can be disregarded after reasoned analysis (5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges, b)).  Change the value of the generic constant and you change it's length.  If it's an error it's a problem with Lattice and can be worked around as per Paebbels/Kevin and Brian's answers. The LRM doesn't define it as an error.

Comment: @David : Yes, I mis-spoke in simply accepting it as an error. Though it doesn't matter : if Lattice mistakenly doesn't accept it, he does need a workaround.

Comment: I upvoted your answer @Brian, it's elegant (5.2.2.1, enumeration literals only have to be unique, they have an associated value).  The comment was directed at clarifying the question.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.  I do need a workaround, but my question was actually not necessarily looking for one.  I was more curious if the syntax itself was legally allowed by VHDL, which David says that the LRM does not define it as an error.  I filed a ticket with Lattice support, so it's up to them if they want to change this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a string for a generic is legal. However look at the actual error message : it is perfectly clear.

One solution would be to make all the strings the same length. `Test_g : IF g_Mode = "Testxx" GENERATE` should compile and work as expected.

A better solution - since a string comparison adds no real value here - might be to declare an enumeration type `type Mode is (Normal, Test, Special);` in a package, and make your generic of type Mode. (This also avoids accidents with mis-spellings for example)

Or if there will only ever be two modes, make the generic a boolean called `Testing`. Then the normal case becomes `if not Testing generate...`

Comment: Thanks Brian for the workaround.  I would just like to point out to anyone else reading this that the syntax in the example above is technically allowed by VHDL.  I have submitted a support ticket to Lattice regarding this behavior.

Comment: Good for reporting it. Worth updating the question with the outcome... (Apparently I'm not allowed to say "+1" at the start of a comment.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's valid.

Example:
In newer IP cores and primitives, Xilinx changed the types of generics to strings, because it's a common ground with Verilog and it avoids several bugs in Vivado's type and generic handling.

To suppress the unequal string comparison warning, you could declare a function like this:

```
function str_equal(str1 : STRING; str2 : STRING) return BOOLEAN is
begin
  if str1'length /= str2'length then
    return FALSE;
  else
    return (str1 = str2);
  end if;
end function;
```

Comment: This can be made an overload of the default `"="[string,string return boolean]` operator to suppress the error with normal syntax.

Comment: @Kevin : you are correct; however, that's assuming Lattice tools handle overloads correctly. They may still simply report an error...